# What`s wrong with nodeValue?

Tags: javascript

```
// html
<div>Hello World!</div>

// Javascript
var textNode = div.firstChild;
textNode.nodeValue = "Hello Us";
```

The sample: [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufc3Q.png) Why can`t i change the text content?

Comment: in some browsers, "special" tags like `body` are automagically assigned to their own variables so doing something like `body.firstChild` would work as expected. #1 it's awful practice to rely on this since support is extremely non-cross-browser and #2 it's silly to expect this to work on a tag like `div` where there could easily be more than one div on a page. which `<div>` would `div` refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was you weren't declaring your `div` variable. I presume you must have got some error. Just reference the `div` for which you want to change the `nodeValue` and everything seems good.. Below, I've referred it with `getElementsByTagName`, you can use any of other options if required.

```js
// Javascript
var div=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var textNode = div.firstChild;
textNode.nodeValue = "Hello Us";
console.log(textNode.nodeValue);
```

```html
<div>Hello World!</div>
```

Comment: It`s work. But why should add [0] behind the ('div')?

Comment: @K.Wu That's what I mentioned.. There are different ways of referring an element.. `document.getElementsByTagName` is the one.. Others are like `document.getElementsByClassName`,`document.getElementById` etc., Please read more about these and how to use...

Comment: What I mean is if i don't add [0], that way just doesn't work. and `document.getElementById` can work.

Comment: Yes.. because `document.getElementsByTagName` and `document.getElementsByClassName` returns elements as `array` as the name says `getElements` and hence you have to refer it by index. But `document.getElementById` returns only one `element` as `id` should be unique per page..

Comment: Oops.How can i forget about it. Thanks for your patience. :-)

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to include an id attribute to that div since it is very likely you have other divs and that can give you trouble.

```
// html
<div id="myDivId">Hello World!</div>

// Javascript
var node = document.getElementById("myDivId");
node.textContent = "Hello Us";
```

if you are using jQuery, easier:

```
jQuery("#myDivId").html("Hello Us");
```